# Failed to open stream PHP fopen() not working

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to create .txt files on my server, after given input, but i get the error shown at the bottom.

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET["firstname"]. " ". $_GET["lastname"].".txt";

$myfile = fopen("$filename", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "Stuur een leuk berichtje naar deze persoon: ". $_GET["emailadres"];

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

I get the error:

> Warning: fopen(test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in /home/students/57fasdf6/www/bevestiging.php on line 37 Unable
>   to open file!

Thanks in advance!

Greets,

Rex

Comment: well, just take a minute to reflect about what "permission denied" might *mean*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is throwing that error is, php need to have write permissions on that folder, Try to give it write permissions and try again

Comment: Thanks man! Stupid of me, it worked :D

Answer (score 3):

At your server there has some permission issue. If you want to write/read in your server file the directory permission of that file is 777 and file permission is 755.

You can change your file permission by the following command:-

PATH OF THE LOCATION FOLDER....   chmod 777 FOLDER NAME

PATH OF THE LOCATION FOLDER....   chmod 755 FILE NAME